# JBoss WebServices and EJB

Tags: web-services, ejb, jboss6.x

My application should show a list of stuff over RESTful WebServices.

This list of stuff is generated via an EJB which is deployed in JBoss AS 6 in a .jar.

My question is, how do I get this list of stuff in order to show it via Web Services?
If I try to inject @EJB  in the stateless bean annotated with @WebService, and try to invoke the method that generates the list, <strike>I get an error saying that @EJB cannot be resolved (or imported).</strike> (fixed it, needed to modify maven dependencies). 
Now I get a `NullPointerException` when I call the supposedly injected EJB...

I am using the webapp archetype from Maven, which contains an EAR, a JAR and a WAR.

I am at a total loss here, been trying to figure this for almost a week.

Thanks in advance!

--EDIT-- code and typo fixed

This is my stateless bean which SHOULD be exposed as a WebService (according to:
http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/restful_calculator_with_javascript_and )

```
@Stateless
@Path("/MyRESTApplication")
public class HelloWorldResource {
    @EJB
    private TestBean testBean;

    @GET()
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return testBean.doMoreStuff();
    }
}
```

the `doMoreStuff()` function simply returns "HELLO!".

Comment: We need code samples, can't help you otherwise.

Comment: Can you update your post with relevant code & is this typo - `inject my Web Service with @EJB`.

Comment: updated question with code, typo fix and updated error.